# Find out if a given point is within the "area of polygon" - GoogleMaps API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a web project where the idea is: users (A) can define an address each with the help of GoogleMaps API and with that i can get the coordenates and store them in database. Then other users (B) can design a polygon area on a map, again with GoogleMaps API, they would submit that area, and with that value the page would be able to find if there is any user (A) in that area.

How can i do it or where can i find information about this specific matter?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Comment: Yes, it would help, but there's a problem, cause if i have lots of addresses i need to check one by one...not good. Perhaps it would be easiar if i could know that the polygon begins at latitude X and ends at latitude Y as well as longitude. This way I would get a "square" which would limit the amount of addresses as a result. Is it possible to get this information from poligno?

Comment: A google.maps.Polygon does not have a property "bounds" (at least didn't the last time I read the documentation).  You can easily compute the bounds of a polygon.

Comment: Note that your question specifically asks about "a" point.

Comment: You'r right and i'm sorry for that. But the description of the question is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API v3 geometry library now includes the [poly namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly), which has a containsLocation method:

containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)
 boolean
 Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

pass it a reference to the point and the polygon and it will tell you whether the polygon contains the point.

To compute the bounds of a polygon, iterate over the points in all its paths (can be simplified if you know it only has one path), adding them to a bounds object with google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend()